# Equivalent to get_contents_to_file in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

In boto3, is there an equivalent of [`get_contents_to_file`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.get_contents_to_file), that copies the contents of an object to a file handle?

In boto, if I have an S3 object `key`, I can copy the contents to a temporary file with:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
key = code_that_gets_key()

with TemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
    key.get_contents_to_file(key, tmpfile)
```

I haven't found an equivalent in boto3.

I have been able to replace usage of [`get_contents_to_filename`](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.get_contents_to_filename) with [`download_file`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=download_file#S3.Object.download_file). However, that covers the case where I provide the filename. In this case, I want to provide the file handle as the argument.

Currently, I can get the code to work in boto3 by iterating over the body as follows:

```
with TemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
    body = key.get()['Body']
    for chunk in iter(lambda: body.read(4096), b''):
        filehandle.write(chunk)
```

Is there a better way to do this in boto3?

Comment: Can't you pass `tmp_file.name` to `download_file()` ?

Comment: @helloV In this case I could use [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which has a filename. I'm not sure whether that's a good idea, since the `download_file` method will open a new file handle for the same file. In general, not all file handles have file names (e.g. `StringIO`, `TemporaryFile`).

Comment: Isn't this what [download_fileobj](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj) is for?

Comment: @PeterBrittain yes, `download_fileobj` is exactly what I'm looking for. Looks like it's new in version 1.4.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of [V1.4.0](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/upgrading.html) there is a [`download_fileobj`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_fileobj) function that does exactly what you want. As per the formal documentation:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
obj = bucket.Object('mykey')

with open('filename', 'wb') as data:
    obj.download_fileobj(data)
```

The operation is also available on the [bucket resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_fileobj) and [s3 client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) as well, for example:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')

with open('filename', 'wb') as data:
    bucket.download_fileobj('mykey', data)
```

Comment: Whoops, that should be `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`. Mea culpa, the docs should be updated shortly. It is also worth noting that this operation is available on the [s3 client](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj) and [Object resource](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.download_fileobj) as well.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Thanks!  I feel I should have spotted that when doing the excerpt...

Comment: Thanks Peter and @JordonPhillips. In my case it was the object version that I was specifically looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer would be to use NamedTemporaryFile instead of TemporaryFile:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp_file:
    file_name = tmp_file.name # This is what you are looking for
```

More docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

Comment: This works for the example I gave, but it's not the general solution I'm looking for. As I said in the comments, not all file handles have filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer is correct, but I would like to note that currently much of AWS does not have boto3 1.4 deployed, most notably AWS Lambda.

This doesn't prevent you from upgrading on the fly, but in case you're runing code on fresh installs make sure to check that

```
boto3.__version__ >= '1.4.0'
```

and upgrade the library if not. Hopefully this will be fixed soon and this will be moot.

Answer (score 0):

### Please be careful to the most upvoted answer.

the **get_contents_to_file** does not do exactly the same as **download_fileobj**.

**get_contents_to_file** can append multiple files from s3 to a single file object.
**download_fileobj** cannot append multiple files from s3 to a single file object.

**Only if you just get a single s3 file to a single file object, they work the same.**

example:

```
def download_files(self, s3_key_list, f):
    for s3_key, in s3_key_list:
        s3_key_object = self.s3_hook.get_key(s3_key, self.s3_bucket)
        s3_key_object.get_contents_to_file(f)  # append all the s3 files to a single file object

def download_files(self, s3_key_list, f):
    for s3_key, in s3_key_list:
        s3_key_object = self.s3_hook.get_key(s3_key, self.s3_bucket)
        s3_key_object.download_fileobj(f)  # unable to do that, it overwrites the object, you have to use a for loop.
```